# How do i print the whole string in "startswith" method

Tags: python

e.g: From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008. 
I want to pull this line from a text file:mbox-short.txt

Sample code below only pulls: From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za and not the whole line with TIME

Code:

```
fh = open(fname)
di = dict()
for email in fh :
    if not email.startswith ('From:'): continue
    print(email)
```

Comment: Can you add the file mbox-short.txt content?

Comment: It seems that your content is not just on line because you do nothing to remove anthing

Answer (score 0):

Did you observe that your file does not have `":"` after `From` and your code does. Assuming that is the case, you may want to run the below code and it would work.

```
fh = open(fname)
di = dict()
for email in fh :
    if not email.startswith ('From'): continue
    print(email)
```

If this does not work, you might want to share the content of the input file or the file itself so that we can try to help.

Comment: @Bulelani : Did it work ? Your feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is a better practice to use a context manager:

```
with open(fname) as fh:
    di = dict()
    for email in fh :
        if email.startswith('From:'): print(email)
```